# How to Debug Zapier Intergrations That Use REST API?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, zapier, zapier-cli

I have a Zapier integration that pulls the information from this Web API project I implemented using .NET Framework. The integration is not working as it supposed to and some fields are getting set incorrectly somewhere in between and I don't really know where to look.

Is there any way to debug the integration on my local in a way that it uses the local version of Web API, so that I could carefully examine the data going out and coming in?

Answer (score 0):

`zapier logs --type http` will show you all the calls made with `z.request`. You can also run a debugger against your unit tests locally using the JS test runner of your choice.